# Why Google Guice not able to intialized the i18n object and giving me null

Tags: java, guice

I am writing J-unit test case for one my method.

A.java

```
 void resetToolbar(final ListSelectionModel lastSelectionModel) {
        // attempt to restore the previous page
        if (toolbar != null && lastSelectionModel != null) {
            gridPanel.setSelectionModel(lastSelectionModel);
        }
       // Issue occur here..... In PagingToolbar.
        toolbar = new PagingToolbar();
    }
```

PagingToolbar.java

```
class PagingToolbar {
    @Inject
    private transient I18nUtils i18n;

    /**
     * Creates a new paging toolbar.
     */
    public PagingToolbar() {
        super();
        setDisplayingItemsText(i18n.getText(this, "facebook")); 
    // here i18n get null and throws null pointer-exception.
```

}

ATest.java

```
class editorModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(I18nUtils.class)
                .to((Class < ? extends I18nUtils >) A.class);

    }
}
@Test(groups = { "unit" })
public class ATest extends AbstractModule {

    @Test
    public void resetToolbar(){

        I18nUtils i18n = createNiceMock(I18nUtils.class);
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new editorModule());
        A editor = injector.getInstance(A.class);

        // Invoke
        A tt = new A();
        tt.resetToolbar(listselectmodelMock);
    }
}
```

NOTE : In A class in resetToolbar() , I have to invoke pagingToolbar with new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating `PagingToolbar` yourself with `new PagingToolbar();`.

Comment: Yes you are right But I cannot refactor the code as such There is only few lines.

Comment: Is there any way to configure() bind in test class and invoke from there So it persist to invoke like Google-Guice injector worked

Comment: While running application i18n fetch proper data without giving me null and resetToolbar works fine. But For testing It not fetch proper data.

Comment: It even can't work in production if code is same `toolbar = new PagingToolbar();`.

Comment: The `PagingToolbar` must be injected or obtained through `Injector#getInstance` method.

Comment: Another possibility is that the production code is injecting members with `Injector#injectMembers` method.

Comment: Can u guide me to understand @Amit, what is means by injecting member with Injector#injectMembers method.

Comment: You can inject members annotated with `@Inject` using this method in case when you have to create the target instance yourself.

Answer (score 0):

## Use a `Provider`

In your **`A.java`**:

```
class A {

  private final Provider<PagingToolbar> pagingToolbarProvider;
  private PagingToolbar toolbar;

  @Inject
  A(Provider<PagingToolbar> pagingToolbarProvider) {
    this.pagingToolbarProvider = pagingToolbarProvider;
    this.toolbar = pagingToolbarProvider.get();
  }

  void resetToolbar(final ListSelectionModel lastSelectionModel) {
    // attempt to restore the previous page
    if (toolbar != null && lastSelectionModel != null) {
        gridPanel.setSelectionModel(lastSelectionModel);
    }
    toolbar = pagingToolbarProvider.get();
  }

}
```